# Timer is not starting(EasyTimer.js)

Tags: javascript, timer

Want to test a library called EasyTimer.js(https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/#libraryLoadExample) ...doing the same as its docs says but the timer is not starting...

someone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Timer</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="basicUsage">00:00:00</div>

    <script src="easytimer.js"></script>
    <script>
        var timerInstance = new easytimer.Timer();

    </script>
    <script>
        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.start();
        timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function(e) {
            $('#basicUsage').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything work ok. Remove `var timerInstance = new easytimer.Timer();`

```js
  var timer = new Timer();
  timer.start();
  timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function(e) {
      $('#basicUsage').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/easytimer@1.1.1/src/easytimer.min.js"></script>

<div id="basicUsage">00:00:00</div>
```

Comment: Hi alexander can we put the whole easytimer.min.js into the code and not use an external link?
I tried to put up the whole code in my js file, it throws an error in console saying Timer(a function of easytimer) is not defined...